# Return #N/A error from ExcelDNA

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, excel-dna

I'm pretty new to `excelDNA`, so I may be missing something obvious. I'm trying to return a `#N/A` from an `excelDNA` UDF. The function I'm using (via Visual Studio 2010) is below:

```
public static object returnError()
{
    return ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA;
}
```

When called from an Excel worksheet, this returns a `#VALUE` - But I need a `#N/A`. I can't just return the string "#N/A", as the Excel functions like `iserror()` won't work on it.

Replacing the `ExcelErrorNA` with any other error types, for example `ExcelErrorDiv0` still yields the `#VALUE`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: return values other than #VALUE! can only be returned from Variant functions

Comment: Sorry - what does this mean? Are you suggesting "public static variant returnError" instead of "object"? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - it looks like you have to stop the ExcelDNA.Integration reference from copying locally to get this. Original thread I found here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/MeYq0-LiGLM